# How can I swap the values of specific indices of my List

Tags: list, indexing, swap

I have a List called `myqueue` and I'm trying to swap the values of two specific indexes in my List.

Here is what I have so far:

```
private Comparator<T> cc;
private List<T> myQueue;
   
private void exch(int i, int j) {  // helper method to exchange items at indices i and j
    T temp = this.myQueue.get(i) ;
    T temp1 = this.myQueue.get(j);
    this.myQueue.get(i) = temp1;
    this.myQueue.get(j) = temp;

}
```

However, there is a compilation error when I do this, which says "Variable expected". I'm confused on what I should do to resolve this. The first thoughts that come to my mind was to do this:

```
private void exch(int i, int j) {  // helper method to exchange items at indices i and j
    T temp = this.myQueue.get(i) ;
    T temp1 = this.myQueue.get(j);
    temp = temp1;
    temp1 = temp;
    temp = this.myQueue.get(i) ;
    temp1 = this.myQueue.get(j)
```

since I tried to use variables, but that would also not work as well. Can someone please help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use a get method to set a value.

If you read oracle documentation [Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) you can find that the [get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-) method only return values, you could use [set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-) method and the index that you want to change to modify the list